# How to detect audio connection between two chrome browser windows using jave code in selenium tests?

Tags: java, selenium, audio

I have invoked two apps from selenium. One browser window has customer app and the other agent app. Now, agent initiates a audio call to customer. The connection is successfull. I know connection is successful based on some new UI elements on agent side that show up. But, how do i verify if there is audio connection actually between these two browser windows using java code? Also, if i mute audio from agent side, how to make sure audio connection is now only one way, i.e from customer browser window to agent browser window and does not exist from agent window to customer window?

Comment: I would be rather surprised to hear that either of those things is possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can set volume value like this

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("document.querySelector('locator').volume = 0.3;");
jse.executeScript("return document.querySelector('locator').muted");
```

Comment: This doesn't help me in determining whether there is an audio connection between two browser instances

Comment: is it BDD scenario?

Comment: Are there libraries which can be used to access chrome webrtc internals and get what i want, coz webrtc internals statistics shows which browser tab or window has webrtc happening rite?

Comment: I don't undestand properly

Comment: Ok. chrome://webrtc-internals gives stats right if any of the browser windows is running webrtc audio or video. What i'm asking is, if these stats are possible to be read via a library or something